# Asynchronously populating two elements with ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm displaying the results of two ajax calls in two HTML elements:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var stop_id = $('#services').data("stopid");
    $("#services").load("/stops/" + stop_id + "/services");
    $("#times").load("/stops/" + stop_id + "/times");
});
```

In the XHR view I can see that the first callback returns shortly, but the element in the webpage is not populated immediately. It looks like both elements are populated at the same instant, and it's only when the longer call returns.

1. Why does it behave like this?
2. How can I make sure each HTML element is populated as soon as the data is received from the server?

Comment: can you show the code you're using to do the ajax calls?

Comment: @kinakuta I posted all the relevant code. What seems to be missing?

Comment: Try changing `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte `$(document).ready` causes an infinite loop of ajax calls. Why should it matter anyway? I'm pretty sure `$(window).load` is not part of the problem, because the ajax does work.

Comment: is there any other script that might be keeping the browser busy? what you have shared looks just fine

Comment: That's odd that it causes an infinite loop of ajax calls... It was just a shot in the dark because it looks like it should have worked as-is. Have you checked your console timeline to confirm that the requests are returning at different times? Is one set of data considerably larger than the other?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Yes, they return at different times (1.5 sec vs 2.5 sec), but are displayed only after the latest one returns.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks, this could be some other performance issue. I'll try to test it by making the second call extra-long and see what happens.

Comment: You might even try commenting out the second call to see if the first one renders on time.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added a 10-second sleep to the second call on the server side, and the problem persists. Even though the first call returns after 1.5 sec, it now takes over 10 seconds to display its results.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Thanks, I tried it, and yes - when there is no second call, the first call's data is shown much faster.

Comment: @IlyaKogan can you remove the second ajax request and see whether it is loading fast

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, it does load faster without the second request.

Comment: Just had a look in the jQuery source code to verify that there isn't any caching or such going on in jQuery, so the problem would seem to be your browser. Have you tried this on different browsers?